# poor performance of view built on base views

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, query-optimization

I have an Oracle view (using 11gR2) which is a join of three other views, i.e.:

```
create or replace view main_vw as
select a.*, b.*, c.*
from a_vw a, b_vw b, c_vw c
where a.b_id = b.b_id
and a.c_id = c.c_id
```

Doing "select * from main_vw" hangs for hours, and EXPLAIN PLAN shows a very inefficient query plan.  Yet, if create the logically equivalent steps as:

```
create table a_tbl as select * from a_vw;
create table b_tbl as select * from b_vw;
create table c_tbl as select * from c_vw;
select a.*, b.*, c.*
from a_tbl a, b_tbl b, c_tbl c
where a.b_id = b.b_id and a.c_id = c.c_id;
```

All four statements complete in under 5 seconds.

Is there any way I can use hints or something to get Oracle's optimizer to evaluate the sub-views first, and then join them as if they were tables?

I've looked at the hints 'QB_NAME', 'NO_EXPAND', 'NO_REWRITE' to no avail...

Note:  a_vw, b_vw, and c_vw in this example are quite complex queries, and they do reference base tables in common.  They also reference a settings table, whose contents is customized at the session level and affects what is returned.  So, I cannot create tables from these views.

Answer (score 2):

Use `ROWNUM` to force Oracle to evaluate inline views independently.

```
create or replace view main_vw as
select a.*, b.*, c.*
from
  (select * from a_vw where rownum >= 1 /*prevent transformations*/) a,
  (select * from b_vw where rownum >= 1 /*prevent transformations*/) b,
  (select * from c_vw where rownum >= 1 /*prevent transformations*/) c
where a.b_id = b.b_id
and a.c_id = c.c_id
```

This looks odd at first.  The `ROWNUM` doesn't appear to do anything.  But [`ROWNUM`](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/pseudocolumns009.htm#SQLRF00255) is a special pseudo-column used for sorting that "can affect view optimization".  In practice it prevents *all* optimizations and is the only safe way to completely isolate code.  This method is also useful for type-safety, such as a Entity-Attribute-Value pattern where everything is stored as a string and must be processed in a specific order.

As you've already discovered, hints are difficult to get right.  Even if you do get them right now there's a good chance they won't work properly when the query is modified by another developer in the future.  To prevent them from removing this cryptic predicate make sure to add a comment.

This won't necessarily solve the root performance problem but it should at least make it exponentially easier to solve.  The over-all explain plan should include three sections that match the explain plans for each inline view.  If each inline view runs well you only need to worry about the two joins between them.

Comment: Hi John, Thanks very much for your response.  I tried it and indeed, after using the `ROWNUM >= 1` condition, the `EXPLAIN PLAN` looks much better, hitting indexes rather than doing full table scans.  Bizarrely, though, even with this promising `EXPLAIN PLAN`, the query itself takes 7 minutes to complete.  When I instead do a `CREATE TABLE AS SELECT ` for each of the three individual views, and then do a query using those three tables, the entire process still takes under one second. ;(

Comment: Do the three queries each run quickly by themselves?  Maybe just one of them has a problem.  (And make sure you're comparing the time to return all the rows, not just the first N.)

Comment: Yes, by 'entire process', i mean four CTAS statements.  The first three are `CREATE TABLE A_TAB AS SELECT * from A_VW` etc, then doing `CREATE TABLE MAIN_TAB AS SELECT a.*, b.*, c.* from A_TAB A, B_TAB B, C_TAB C where A.B_ID = B.B_ID and A.C_ID = C.C_ID`  I do it this way to cut the printing / network time out of the measurement.

Comment: Perhaps the plan for joining those three inline views is awful; although a single inline view may run quickly it's possible that the whole plan has it running a large number of times.  Maybe there's a `MERGE JOIN CARTESIAN` in the explain plan section between the three views?  If the queries are complex this might be a time to use a hint.  It's common for the optimizer to under-estimate the row counts for large queries.  If you know the real row count, try a hint like ` ... (select /*+ cardinality(2000) */ ...` (replace 2000 with a real number) for some of the inline views.